# No such file error in System Workbench for STM32

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, stm32

I get an error saying 
`fatal error: stm32l0xx_hw_conf.h: No such file or directory`
even though I have included `stm32l0xx_hw_conf.h` in the same project. How do I solve this error?

[image]

Edit: The console output for this error is:

> Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Debug
>   arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft
>   -DHAL_OK -DSTM32L0 -DSTM32L071xx -DUSE_MIROMICO_FMLR -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_BAND_868 -DSENSOR_ENABLED -DDEBUG -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/inc"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Include"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/FMLR" -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Crypto"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Mac"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Phy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Utilities"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/Common" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/sts_sht_21"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/bmp280" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Core"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das/Phy"  -Og -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/debug.d" -MT"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/debug.o" -o "Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/debug.o"
>   "/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/src/debug.c"
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Debug
>   arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft
>   -DHAL_OK -DSTM32L0 -DSTM32L071xx -DUSE_MIROMICO_FMLR -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_BAND_868 -DSENSOR_ENABLED -DDEBUG -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/inc"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Include"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/FMLR" -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Crypto"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Mac"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Phy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Utilities"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/Common" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/sts_sht_21"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/bmp280" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Core"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das/Phy"  -Og -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/hw_gpio.d" -MT"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/hw_gpio.o" -o "Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/hw_gpio.o"
>   "/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/src/hw_gpio.c"
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Debug
>   arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft
>   -DHAL_OK -DSTM32L0 -DSTM32L071xx -DUSE_MIROMICO_FMLR -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_BAND_868 -DSENSOR_ENABLED -DDEBUG -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/inc"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/SW4STM32/Miromico-FMLR/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Include"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/FMLR" -I../../../../../../../../Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Crypto"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Mac"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Phy"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Utilities"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/Common" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/sts_sht_21"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/Components/bmp280" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Middlewares/Third_Party/Lora/Core"
>   -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das" -I"/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Drivers/BSP/sx1272mb2das/Phy"  -Og -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/bsp.d" -MT"Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/bsp.o" -o "Projects/MultiSensorHub/src/bsp.o"
>   "/home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/src/bsp.c"
>   In file included from
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/inc/hw.h:72:0,from
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/src/bsp.c:50:
>   /home/dinesh/fmlr_bitbucket/lorawan/Projects/Multi/Applications/LoRa/MultiSensorHub/inc/hw_conf.h:123:10:
>   fatal error: stm32l0xx_hw_conf.h: No such file or directory #include
>   "stm32l0xx_hw_conf.h"

Comment: These errors ("Problems" tab) are sometimes questionable. They're not really compiler output, they come from Eclipse/CDT module that does static analysis and attempts to show you errors in real time before you even compile your code. It usually works ok but may sometimes fail, e.g. when indexer has old data. Try to build your project instead and copy-paste your build console output (both compiler command lines and errors).

Comment: @JacekŚlimok I did build the project and the same error persists. I will add the console output too.

Comment: Include compiler command line please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the path to the include file in the project setting (if its a managed project) or the makefile if it is not. Adding a file to the project does not add it to the include path.

Comment: I did add the path by going to Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Includes. I selected the path through File System and added it. I am still getting the error.

Comment: I suspect you have an error in the path or name. Double check. It is a very easy mistake to make. If it is included in any assembler it may need adding to the includes under the assembler tab

Comment: Added to GCC compiler includes. I added to Assembler too. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you need to re-index the project. In Eclipse, you can right click the project and select Index->Rebuild.

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog can you add a screen capture of your build path includes in the Eclipse project settings?